If strings are immutable then what the heck is this?
In python strings are immutable meaning they can't be changed and when we apply a method we are getting a new string...
explain to me how does this work then?
str1 = "fdjsklafdsa"
str1 = str1.replace("fdjsklafdsa", "This")

print(str1)

result -> This
is this creating a new string of str1? What happens to the previous one?? I'm confused pls help

Yes, you're creating a new string - and since the original string is no longer referenced it can eventually be garbage collected :)

= in python rebinds a name. It is unlike the assignment you may have learnt from other programming languages.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace replace returns a copy of the string

You are creating a changed copy with .replace, then assign that copy to str1. So str1 is now the new string. The old string is no longer assigned to a variable.
